# Building a Node class with PHP

Tags: php, class, tree, nodes

I need to build a Node class that will represent a tree of nodes and all these nodes to be saved in an array. I know the structure with pseudo code and C++ but i cat think for the best structure in PHP ?

something like this:

```
class Node 
{
 //number of nodes from 0 to n
}
```

Comment: why not simply use an array?

Comment: You should expand your post a little bit. What is the structure you know in C++? Why can't you convert it to PHP? What problems come up?

Comment: yep, to short. before trying to write anything silly check the spl : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php

Comment: How I can make it with array ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider  [Ardent](https://github.com/morrisonlevi/Ardent) it has good [Binary Tree](https://github.com/morrisonlevi/Ardent/blob/master/src/Ardent/BinaryTree.php) Implementation and also supports [BinarySearchTree](https://github.com/morrisonlevi/Ardent/blob/master/src/Ardent/BinarySearchTree.php)

**Example :**

```
    $root = new BinaryTree(7);
    $root->setLeft(new BinaryTree(5));
    $root->setRight(new BinaryTree(8));
    $root->getLeft()->setLeft(new BinaryTree(1));
    $root->getLeft()->setRight(new BinaryTree(6));
    $root->getRight()->setRight(new BinaryTree(9));
```

You can also have [AvlTree](https://github.com/morrisonlevi/Ardent/blob/master/src/Ardent/AvlTree.php) which extends BinarySearchTree

```
$object = new AvlTree();
    //          5
    //        /    \
    //       2      9
    //     /  \    / \
    //    1    4  8  11
    //        /
    //       3
    $object->add(5);
    $object->add(2);
    $object->add(9);
    $object->add(1);
    $object->add(4);
    $object->add(8);
    $object->add(11);
    $object->add(3);
```